# ARCH Error Terms

Tags: garch, arch

In ARCH models (and other models from the same family), why do we assume $\epsilon_t$ is specifically defined as it is below? Why is the first term the standard deviation as opposed to variance, and why is the second one white noise? The white noise confuses me more than anything; why do we need it? Why must it have a variance of 1 specifically? 
$$r_t=\epsilon_t$$ 
$$\sigma_t^2=\omega+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2$$ 
where
$$\epsilon_t=\sigma_te_t$$ 
$$e_t \tilde\ i.i.d.  N(0,1)$$

Why not have something like: 
$$\epsilon_t=\sigma_t^2$$
or 
$$\epsilon_t=\sigma_t^2e_t$$ 
Why not have a distribution that follows:
$$e_t \tilde\ i.i.d.  N(0,1.05)$$

Thank you very much. Any insight on the form of $\epsilon_t$ or the general model is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your formulas: you have $\epsilon_t$ in place of $r_t$ three times, $\sigma_t$ is missing in the first formula, and there may be more.

Comment: I am taking a graduate-level course and this was taken directly from my notes. I double-checked and there are no typos.

Comment: Sorry, with all due respect, the above equations are not correct. I am composing an answer now, you will see how at least the first two should look.

Comment: Your formulas are definitelly wrong. How come $\epsilon_t = \sigma_t \epsilon_t$? Usually you estimate an AR(1) model like this $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$. Imagine that $\phi = 0$, so you have $y_t = \epsilon_t$. In a GARCH model you want to estimate the conditional variance of the error, so you may specify $\epsilon_t$ as $\epsilon_t = \sigma_t \eta_t$ where $\eta_t \sim N(0,1)$, and then $\sigma^2 = \omega + \alpha y_{t-1}^2$.

Comment: Ah yes, I did mix up my notation (should have been an e instead of epsilon). Apologies; it is fixed now and in line with my notes.

Comment: I have updated my answer to respond to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form of ARCH(1) model is

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
r_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t \\
\sigma^2_t &= \omega + \alpha_1 r^2_{t-1} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

where $\varepsilon_t \sim i.i.d.(0,1)$. (Note that the distribution need not be normal.)

- Why is $\varepsilon_t$ $i.i.d.$?

This is to make the model complete and simple. If $\varepsilon_t$ were not $i.i.d.$, there would still be some structure in the model errors, hence the model would not be complete. You would need to model the underlying structure further until you get $i.i.d.$ errors; otherwise you would not be able to directly apply estimation methods such as maximum likelihood estimation that assume $i.i.d.$ errors. Also, if you want a more flexible model, you are free to play with its functional form instead of removing the $i.i.d.$'ness of errors.

- Why unit variance?

$\varepsilon_t$ has unit variance for the purpose of normalization. In principle it could have any variance as long as it is common for all $t$. Specifying the variance to be unity is just convenient. A constant variance is needed because the functional form of the ARCH model is intended for reflecting the nature of the non-constant conditional variance, and having a non-constant variance of $\varepsilon_t$ would be a nuisance. (Also see the argument for why we need $i.i.d.$'ness.)

- What do I mean by "scaling"?

You can think of $r_t$ as a scaled version of $\varepsilon_t$, and vice versa. In an ARCH(1) model, $r_t$ would be $i.i.d.$ if not for scaling, i.e. if not for the multiplication of $\varepsilon_t$ by $\sigma_t$.

- Why scale by $\sigma_t$ rather than $\sigma^2_t$?

The first equation has $\sigma_t$ rather than $\sigma^2_t$ to indicate scaling, and scaling is normally done by dividing or multiplying by the standard deviation rather than the variance. You could specify your own rules, but this is the common way.

- Can you observe the $\varepsilon_t$?

No, you cannot; but you can obtain the fitted values $\hat\varepsilon_t$ from the model; they are called "standardized residuals". Similarly, you cannot observe model errors in a linear regression; you only have their fitted values, i.e. the model residuals.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I mixed up e and epsilon in my notation. I have a few quick follow-ups if that's fine.
What exactly do you mean by "scaling"?
Why do we need (using your notation) $\epsilon_t$ at all? What would the practical implications be of instead specifying returns as $r_t=\sigma_t? The white noise confuses me so much. How can you even observe it in the first place?
Again, thank you very much. This is very helpful!

Comment: $r_t=\sigma_t$*

Comment: Specifying returns as $r_t=\sigma_t$ does not make sense to me. Specifying $r_t\sim d(0,\sigma^2_t)$ makes more sense, but see my last paragraph. Specifying $\epsilon~\sim i.i.d.(0,1)$ is much stricter and allows direct application of maximum likelihood. Without that you cannot do it because scaled $r_t$s may have different distributions (e.g. it allows $r_1$ to be normal and $r_2$ to have some other distribution). Regarding "how can you observe it" -- you cannot.